# Hiding a custom quick access button in Sharepoint 2007 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, toolbar

I created a quick access button in the editing toolbar of a Sharepoint 2007 site, modified the CustomQuickAccess.xml file to include my buttons

Wrote the code behind to handle the postback, etc.  What I want to do is hide the button for certain content types or based on metadata for the document.  I override the visible property etc in my code behind and try to hide but the button still displays.  Thanks in advance for your help.  Below is the code behind for button/console action (as well as CustomQuickAccess.xml markup):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Console>
    <references>
        <reference TagPrefix="myToolbar"
        assembly="MyCustom_PageEditToolbarQuickAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f3a1dd21f335f2ad"
        namespace="MyCustom_PageEditToolbarQuickAccess" />
    </references>
    <structure>
        <ConsoleNode 
            Action="myToolbar:PageEditingToolbarArchive"
            DisplayText="Archive Item" 
            ConfigMenu="Add"
            UseResourceFile="false" 
            Sequence="1900" 
            RequiredRightsMode="Any"
            HideIfDisabled="true"
            ID="ArchiveItem" />
        <ConsoleNode 
            Action="MyToolbar:PageEditingToolbarRetain"
            DisplayText="Keep Item" 
            ConfigMenu="Add"
            UseResourceFile="false" 
            Sequence="1901" 
            RequiredRightsMode="Any"
            HideIfDisabled="true"
            ID="KeepItem" />
    </structure>
    </Console>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.EditingMenuActions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;

namespace MyCustom_PageEditToolbarQuickAccess
{
    public sealed class PageEditingToolbarArchive : ConsoleAction
    {

    SPListItem _item;

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor
    /// </summary>
    public PageEditingToolbarArchive()
        : base()
    {
        _item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
        this.DisplayText = "Archive Item";
        //this.ImageUrl = "/_layouts/images/bdc1tom.gif";

    }


//HERE IS MY INTENT--------
    //public override bool Visible
    //{
    //    get
    //    {
    //        SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
    //        if (MySPutility.Content.doesContentTypeExpire(item)
    //            return false;
    //        else
    //            return base.Visible;
    //    }
    //    set
    //    {
    //        base.Visible = value;
    //    }
    //}

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the permissions required to use this action, 
    /// otherwise button is disabled
    /// </summary>
    public override SPBasePermissions UserRights
    {
        get {
            if (_item != null && MySPutility.Content.doesContentTypeExpire(_item))
            {
                return SPBasePermissions.EditListItems;
            } else {
                return SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask;
            }
            //return SPBasePermissions.FullMask;
            //return SPBasePermissions.BrowseUserInfo;

        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Page must be published to archive
    /// </summary>
    public override AuthoringStates RequiredStates
    {
        get
        {
            return AuthoringStates.IsPublishingPageTrue;

        }
    }

    public override void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        string destinationListName = MySPutility.PropertyBag.PropertyBagValue("ArchiveLocation", SPContext.Current.ListItem.Web.Site.WebApplication);
        string archivedFileLocation = "";

        if (eventArgument == PageEditingToolbarArchive.ArchivePostBackEventArgument)
        {
            try
            {
                SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.ListItem;
                archivedFileLocation = MySPutility.Site.ArchiveItem(item, ((SPDocumentLibrary)item.Web.Lists[destinationListName]).RootFolder.Url, item.Web);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConsoleNode actionsNode = new ConsoleNode();
                ConsoleNode exitNoArchive = new ConsoleNode(actionsNode);

                exitNoArchive.Action = new ExitWithoutSavingAction();
                exitNoArchive.Action.ID = "archiveDocumentErrorActionNeSave";
                actionsNode.ChildConsoleNodes.Add(exitNoArchive);
                this.ShowError(ex, new ConsoleError(ex.Message, actionsNode));
            }
            finally
            {
                SPUtility.Redirect(archivedFileLocation,
                    SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context);
            }


        }
        //base.RaisePostBackEvent(eventArgument);
    }

    public override string NavigateUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return "javascript:" +
                Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, 
                PageEditingToolbarArchive.ArchivePostBackEventArgument);
        }
        set
        {
            base.NavigateUrl = value;
        }
    }

    private const string ArchivePostBackEventArgument = "archiveDocumentItem";
}
```

}